# Replace number in beginning and last python pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have table like this:

```
   id     a       b
    1    -10      -5
    2    -5       0
    3     0       5
    4     5       10
```

i want to replace to `-9999999` and `9999999` in the beginning and last like this:

```
   id     a       b
    1    -9999999 -5
    2    -5       0
    3     0       5
    4     5       9999999
```

is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: `id` is column or `index`?

Comment: its column @jezrael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use if `id` is column use [`DataFrame.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) for set first row and second column and last row and last column by indexing:

```
df.iat[0, 1] = -9999999
df.iat[-1, -1] = 9999999
print (df)
   id        a        b
0   1 -9999999       -5
1   2       -5        0
2   3        0        5
3   4        5  9999999
```

---

Use if `id` is index set first column:

```
df.iat[0, 0] = -9999999
df.iat[-1, -1] = 9999999
print (df)
          a        b
id                  
1  -9999999       -5
2        -5        0
3         0        5
4         5  9999999
```

Comment: can you explain why its different in using the `[0, 0]` and '[0, 1]' in column and index? by the way thank you. it very helpful

Comment: @kj14 - sure, because `a` is  for first second column and for index `a` is first column